# forking heroku rails app does not work. It says invalid data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am trying to fork an existing heroku app and create a staging app. I use the following command:

```
heroku fork --from tmapp1 --to tmstage1
```

The following is returned:

```
Forking tmapp1... done. Forked to tmstage
 ▸    invalid data

There was an error forking to tmstage.

In order to avoid being charged for any resources on tmstage, it is being destroyed...
```

It is not giving any more information.  How do I get the forking to work?  I  am using ruby on rails 4.1.4 and Ruby 2.2.0

Comment: Is the last tmapp1 build success?

Comment: I had the same error message on a build at about the same time as you reported this, although it was precipated by a `rake db:migrate` and not through the CLI. I just ran it today and it's working again, so I presume the issue was on the Heroku side.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug introduced in the CLI.  Run `heroku update` to get the latest version and this should be resolved.

Comment: Thanks, but that did not work.  I still get the same error.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  Can you open a support ticket?  help.heroku.com/tickets/new  I can get that fixed for you ASAP

Comment: thanks jmccartie, I just made a support ticket: https://help.heroku.com/tickets/265991